# regex exactly omit certain words

Tags: regex

Marked with "#bad" are those who also need to detect.

http://regexr.com/3d697

This publication would not if I had not tried every way I could, please help me?

Sorry for the English, i used the Google translator.
At least I am aware that what is written above is very poorly translated, including this sentence. Jaja.

Comment: Please post here your text, and the regex you tried. Post directly.

Comment: Are you trying to omit the words marked with `#bad`?

Comment: This should be ok `/.+(?=#bad).+/r` to select the ones tagged with `#bad`

Comment: "#bad" And "#good" are only references to indicate which are right or wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
({((?!if|else|else if|\/|\$)\S*)(.*)})
```

instead of this

```
({([^$|if|else|else if|\/if]\S*)(.*)})
```

You use [] is for char

```
[^SOMETHING]
```

escape letter S O M E T H I N G
and ($!) escape string

```
($!SOMETHING)
```

escape SOMETHING

you can take a look of the regex with https://regexper.com/ (it provide a good help to make a regex)

Comment: Problem: should not detect the two in it. regexr.com/3d69d

Comment: like this ? ({((?!if|else| |else if|\/|\$)\S*)([^}]*)})